# Best way to store data in a table row and retrieve via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following php code structure:

- Loop

  - create table row

This essentially creates something like:

```
<tr class="selection">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

When a user clicks on the row, I access the selection like this

```
$(".bet-selection").click(function() {
    //Do some stuff    
});
```

The selection must return JQuery data (more than what I have in the table row).

So I was thinking I would include a jsonEncoded data field, something like this:

```
$encodedData = [1,2,..n];
<tr class="selection" data="encodedData">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

And my idea is to access this data via jQuery like so:

```
$(".bet-selection").click(function() {
    var data = $('.selection').val();
    var dataObject = $.parseJSON( data );
});
```

Obviously this does not work.

So my question is: Is there a standard method for doing something along these lines?

Comment: Please read this! [Everything from a table to array](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/store-html-table-data-to-javascript-array)

Comment: How is .bet-selection related to .selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should store the data in the row with something like this:

```
<?php $encodedData = [1,2,..n]; ?>

<tr class="selection" data-row="<?= json_encode( $encodedData ); ?>">
```

This will store your data in the `data-row` attribute as a json string

Then, to retrieve the data, you can get the json string from the row, and parse it with JS:

```
$(".selection").click(function() {

    //get the clicked row's data 
    var data = $(this).data('row');

    //parse the JSON string 
    var decoded_data = JSON.parse( data );  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render this kind of mark up with your php:

```
<tr class="selection" data-id="123">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

And then render a javascript hash table with php like this:

```
window.myNameSpace.encodedDataHashTable = {
    "123": [2, 20, 10, 1],
    "456": [3, 30, 20, 4]
};
```

And when you handle clicks:

```
$(".bet-selection").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var dataObject = window.myNameSpace.encodedDataHashTable[id];
    console.log(dataObject);
});
```

But what you really seem to need is a front-end framework or a bit of homebrow front-end architecture to handle this kind of thing for you.

In any case, this is how it all would come together:

```js
$(function() {
    window.myNameSpace = window.myNameSpace || {};
  
    window.myNameSpace.encodedDataHashTable = {
        "123": [2, 20, 10, 1],
        "456": [3, 30, 20, 4]
    };

    $(".bet-selection").click(function() {
      console.log(this);
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var dataObject = window.myNameSpace.encodedDataHashTable[id];
        $("#demo").html(dataObject);
    });
});
```

```css
tr:hover { background-color: pink; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="bet-selection" data-id="123">
    <td>2</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bet-selection" data-id="456">
    <td>3</td><td>30</td><td>20</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Last click data: 
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   var table = $('.selection');

   var rowLength = table.rows.length;

   for(var i=0; i<rowLength; i+=1){
      var row = table.rows[i];
   }
```